# Windows не удалось загрузить локально сохраняемый профиль

Tags: windows

Не удалось найти ваш локальный профиль, вход в систему выполнен с временным профилем. Любые изменения профиля будут потеряны при выходе.

следущее событие ошибка:

Windows сохранила архивную копию профиля этого пользователя. Windows будет автоматически пытаться использовать эту копию профиля при следующем входе в систему этого пользователя.

следущее событие ошибка:

Windows не удалось загрузить локально сохраняемый профиль. Возможные причины этой ошибки - недостаточные права безопасности или поврежденный локальный профиль. Если проблема не устраняется, обратитесь к системному администратору.

Помогите!

Answer (score 2):

На Висте пути к профилям прописываются в реестре:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList`

Чтобы заработало, можно заменить поврежденный профиль новым.

1. Сохранить данные из старого профиля, вручную скопировав все нужное из папок.
2. Удалить папку и запись в реестре старого профиля.
3. Войти в систему под администратором и создать новый профиль.
4. Скопировать все, что было сохранено на первом шаге, в нужное место.
5. Произвести необходимые настройки.

Также можно попробовать восстановить систему с помощью службы SystemRestore, откатившись на точку, когда все работало.

Answer (score 0):

Очень похоже на ошибку нехватки места на диске, либо на то что домен не доступен а вот данные для входа почему-то закешировались. Я бы посоветовал системному администратору сообщить. Больше ничего сказать не могу т.к. не телепат.

Answer (score 0):

Для Windows **XP** Microsoft [предлагали](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/318011/-windows-cannot-load-your-profile-because-it-may-be-corrupted-error-me) только [создать новый профиль](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/318011/-windows-cannot-load-your-profile-because-it-may-be-corrupted-error-me) (KB318011) и [скопировать из старого профиля в новый документы и файлы](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/811151) (KB811151)